# Sort array by date in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I am using Coffescript, underscore.js, knockout, and I am trying to sort an array by date, but for some reason its not working

```
let accounts = [
  {
    id: 101,
    content: "abc1",
    createdDate: "2015-12-22T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    content: "abc2",
    createdDate: "2012-12-22T00:00:00"
  }

]
```

This is how I wrote the code in coffeescript

```
_.sortBy(accounts, (a) ->  a.createdDate)
```

The same generated code in JS

```
return this.accounts(_.sortBy(accounts, function(a) {
      return a.createdDate;
    }));
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. I am not getting any error, but the array is not getting sorted by date.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON syntax is invalid and there's no `createdDate` property, it should be like:

```
accounts = [
  {
    id: 102,
    content: "abc",
    createdDate: "2015-12-22T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

So you can use a function as you wrote (use `=>` instead of `->`).

Working example:

```js
let accounts = [
  {
    id: 101,
    content: "abc1",
    createdDate: "2015-12-22T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    content: "abc2",
    createdDate: "2012-12-22T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    id: 103,
    content: "abc3",
    createdDate: "2018-12-22T00:00:00"
  }
]

accounts = _.sortBy(accounts, (a) =>  a.createdDate)
console.log(accounts)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Of course, the `id` and the `content` is just an example.

Comment: The  data I gave was just an example. I am getting my data from an object, the JSon is like this {
    id: 101,
    content: "abc",
    createdDate: "2015-12-22T00:00:00"
  }

Comment: Ok, then I think the only problem is the `-` sign instead of the `=`, check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes I tried this, I put '=' instead of '-', still not working.

Comment: Please include the exact problem and error message in the question.

Comment: I am not getting any error message, the elements in the array are not getting sorted, I need the elements to be sorted by that date

Comment: @Techno Are you assigning the result of `sortBy` back to the original array? `sortBy` does not mutate the original array. @Tamas is doing it in their answer, but you might have missed it: `accounts = _.sortBy(accounts, (a) =>  a.createdDate)`